# how to find how many times the values of a row hit max consecutively

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to find how many times the values of a row hit max consecutively.

- Ps1: My data has 500K rows, so I concern about speed of calculation
- Ps2: In this example, startDay =1 and endDay=7 but some rows have
  different start or end day. (such as startDay=2, endDay=5 or
  startDay=4, endDay=3. arr_bool control this conditions)

My data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
idx = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5',
       'id6', 'id7', 'id8', 'id9', 'id10']
data = {'Day1':[0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
        'Day2':[0,1,1,1,2,1,0,1,1,2],
        'Day3':[1,3,1,1,1,0,0,1,3,2],
        'Day4':[1,2,0,1,1,0,0,2,1,1],
        'Day5':[0,2,1,1,1,1,0,2,1,1],
        'Day6':[1,0,1,1,2,1,0,2,1,1],
        'Day7':[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,3,1]}

startday = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],columns=['start'], index=idx)
endday = pd.DataFrame([7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],columns=['end'], index=idx)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx)
Neg99 = -999
Neg90 = -900
```

I should search the time interval for every rows.(like a loop startday to endday)
I can find the max values in the time interval but I couldn't find the count of the values of a row hit max consecutively.

```py
arr_bool = (np.less_equal.outer(startday.start, range(1,8)) 
            & np.greater_equal.outer(endday.end, range(1,8))
            )
df_result = pd.DataFrame(df.mask(~arr_bool).max(axis=1),
                                        index=idx, columns=['result'])
```

Last conditions:

```py
df_result.result= np.select( condlist = [startday.start > endday.end,
                                         ~arr_bool.any(axis=1)],
                         choicelist = [Neg99,Neg90], 
                         default = df_result.result)
```

The result I want;

```py
result_i_want = pd.DataFrame([2,1,3,6,1,3,0,3,1,2],columns=['result'], index=idx)
```

Here is @WeNYoBen 's solutions but this is running slow;

```py
s=((df.eq(df.max(1),0))&(df.ne(0)))
s.apply(lambda x : x[x].groupby((~x).cumsum()).count().max(),1).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Pure Numpy slicing and stuff

The point of this effort is that OP asked for speed.  This should help.  If you have access to a JIT library like `numba`, you should use that and just loop over each row.

```
sd = startday.start.values
ed = endday.end.values

dr = ed - sd + 1

i = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(dr)
j = np.concatenate([np.arange(s - 1, e) for s, e in zip(sd, ed)])

v = df.values

mx = np.empty(len(v), dtype=v.dtype)
mx.fill(v.min())
np.maximum.at(mx, i, v[i, j])

b = np.ones((v.shape[0], v.shape[1] + 2), bool)

b[i, j + 1] = (v[i, j] != mx[i]) | (mx[i] == 0)

x, y = np.where(b)

y_ = np.diff(y)
mask = y_ > 0
y__ = y_[mask]
x__ = x[1:][mask]

c = np.empty(len(v), int)
c.fill(y__.min())
np.maximum.at(c, x__, y__)

c - 1

array([2, 1, 3, 6, 1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2])
```

---

#### Explanation

I'll leave the obvious alone.

This represents the number of days in each interval

```
dr = ed - sd + 1
```

`i` is the flattened relevant row indices for the corresponding flattened column indices in `j`

```
i = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(dr)
j = np.concatenate([np.arange(s - 1, e) for s, e in zip(sd, ed)])
```

`mx` will be the maximum value for each interval.

`b` will be a boolean array with width 2 more columns wide than `v`.  For this case it looks like:

```
#       Buffer                                                  Buffer
#        /--\                                                    /--\
array([[ True,  True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

The reason for the buffer columns is that I can calculate difference of positions after using `np.where`

Now I populate `b` where the `v` values are not equal to the maximum values in `mx`

```
 #             not equal to max       is equal to zero
 b[i, j + 1] = (v[i, j] != mx[i]) | (mx[i] == 0)
```

Then I find where those positions are in `y`.

By taking the `diff`, I find the number of positions from one instance of not equal to max to the next position of not equal to max.  This will always be one greater than the number we're looking for but we'll correct that later.

Also, the `diff` will reduce the length by one but in reality, there's a bunch of stuff we don't need because I don't need to take the difference from one row relative to a previous row.  Fortunately, I can get rid of all zero or negative differences because they don't make sense.

I use `np.maximum.at` (again) but this time on the differences to find the largest difference and that will be the longest length of consecutive max values for each row.

Mind that it's actually one more than that

Phew.  I'm tired of typing...

Comment: SO should allow people to vote multiple times for answers like this - for effort, explanation and quality :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time!
I tried  your solution but I get error.
First error: `i = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(dr)` line. Error Code: **TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'** And I handled with `i = np.arange(len(df.astype('int64'))).repeat(dr.astype('int64'))` Is that make sense?

If yes, second error is, `np.maximum.at(mx, i, v[i, j])` Error code: **IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type**
And I couldn't this error. (:
Again, thank you for your time.

Comment: Also, if the startday > endday, I should see -999
However, when I run `i = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(dr)`, I get **ValueError: count < 0**

Btw, after import numba, above the errors fixed. (:

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `numpy` solution. First, timings compared to @piRSquared for reference. My code is ~14x faster on a large example while giving the exact same result.

```
# both methods give the expected result on small OP example                                                        
      result                                                                                                    
id1        2                                                                                                    
id2        1                                                                                                    
id3        3                                                                                                    
id4        6                                                                                                    
id5        1                                                                                                    
id6        3                                                                                                    
id7        0                                                                                                    
id8        3                                                                                                    
id9        1                                                                                                    
id10       2                                                                                                    
      result                                                                                                    
id1        2                                                                                                    
id2        1                                                                                                    
id3        3                                                                                                    
id4        6                                                                                                    
id5        1                                                                                                    
id6        3                                                                                                    
id7        0                                                                                                    
id8        3                                                                                                    
id9        1
id10       2

# timings on 50,000 rows random example
pp 12.89263810031116
pi 189.0821446024347
# comparison of results
result    True
dtype: bool
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# OP example
idx = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5',
       'id6', 'id7', 'id8', 'id9', 'id10']
data = {'Day1':[0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
        'Day2':[0,1,1,1,2,1,0,1,1,2],
        'Day3':[1,3,1,1,1,0,0,1,3,2],
        'Day4':[1,2,0,1,1,0,0,2,1,1],
        'Day5':[0,2,1,1,1,1,0,2,1,1],
        'Day6':[1,0,1,1,2,1,0,2,1,1],
        'Day7':[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,3,1]}

startday = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],columns=['start'], index=idx)
endday = pd.DataFrame([7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],columns=['end'], index=idx)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx)
Neg99 = -999
Neg90 = -900

# large example
IDX = [f'id{i}' for i in range(1,50_001)]
STARTDAY, ENDDAY = (pd.DataFrame({c:l}, index=IDX) for c,l in zip(('start','end'), np.sort(np.random.randint(1,8,(2,50_000)), axis=0)))
DF = pd.DataFrame({f'Day{i}':l for i,l in enumerate(np.random.randint(0,4,(7, 50_000)), 1)}, index=IDX)

def pp():
    if restrict_max:
        data = np.where((startday.values<=np.arange(1,8)) & (endday.values>=np.arange(1,8)), df.values, 0)
        mask = data==np.maximum((data==0).all(1), data.max(1))[:, None]
    else:
        mask = (df.values==np.maximum((df.values==0).all(1), df.values.max(1))[:, None]) & (startday.values<=np.arange(1,8)) & (endday.values>=np.arange(1,8))
    y, x = np.where(np.diff(mask, axis=1, prepend=False, append=False))
    y = y[::2]
    x = x[1::2]-x[::2]
    res = np.zeros(df.values.shape[:1], int)
    nl = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(y, prepend=-1))
    res[y[nl]] = np.maximum.reduceat(x, nl)
    return pd.DataFrame({'result': res}, index=df.index)

def pi():
    sd = startday.start.values
    ed = endday.end.values

    dr = ed - sd + 1

    i = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(dr)
    j = np.concatenate([np.arange(s - 1, e) for s, e in zip(sd, ed)])

    v = df.values

    mx = np.empty(len(v), dtype=v.dtype)
    mx.fill(v.min())
    np.maximum.at(mx, i, v[i, j])

    b = np.ones((v.shape[0], v.shape[1] + 2), bool)

    b[i, j + 1] = (v[i, j] != mx[i]) | (mx[i] == 0)

    x, y = np.where(b)

    y_ = np.diff(y)
    mask = y_ > 0
    y__ = y_[mask]
    x__ = x[1:][mask]

    c = np.empty(len(v), int)
    c.fill(y__.min())
    np.maximum.at(c, x__, y__)

    return pd.DataFrame({'result': c - 1}, index=df.index)

restrict_max=True

print(pp())
print(pi())
df, startday, endday = DF, STARTDAY, ENDDAY

from timeit import timeit

print('pp', timeit(pp,number=10)*100)
print('pi', timeit(pi,number=10)*100)
print((pp()==pi()).all())
```

Comment: So glad you answered.  Now I can learn something today.  Like `reduceat`!?

Comment: @piRSquared, You are too kind. I didn't look too closely, but I think your basic strategy is more or less the same as mine. I suppose my code is just a bit more streamlined. Feel free to ask if you need any explanations.

Comment: @piRSquared `reduceat` is like reduce between every pair of consecutive indices (second argument). Here we use the "newline" indices i.e. those where the row index `y` changes to find the length of the longest stretch on that row. Be warned that it behaves badly when indices are not strictly increasing.

Comment: Guys, thank you so much both! My reputation not enough for voting. @piRSquared and Paul Panzer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

Start from defining a function to be applied to each row:

```
def fn(row):
    sd = startday.loc[row.name, 'start'] - 1
    ed = endday.loc[row.name, 'end']
    rr = row.values[sd:ed]
    vMax = rr.max()
    if vMax > 0:
        gr = itertools.groupby(rr)
        return max([ len(list(grp)) for key, grp in gr if key == vMax ])
    else:
        return 0
```

The key difference between `itertools.groupby` (used above) and
`pd.groupby` is that the *itertools* version starts a new group
on **each change** of the source value, so each group contains a series
of the same values (from the current row).

The first stage is to take the proper slice of the current row.

- `sd` is the starting index (including),
- `ed` is the ending index (excluding),
- `rr` is the proper slice (further referred to as *row*).

If the max value in the current row is > 0 then the list comprehension
used above:

- Reads *key* and *grp* (the current group) from the result of *groupby*.
- If the *key* (the value included in the current group) is the
  **maximal** value, then the value added to the result is the length
  of the current group.

The value returned by the function is the **maximum** from this list,
i.e. the length of the longest sequence of maximal values.

If the current row contains only zeroes (max == 0) then return 0.

Then, the only thing to do is to apply the above function to each row:

```
df['result'] = df.apply(fn, axis=1)
```

Of course, you have to *import itertools*.

The advantage of my solution over the other answer is that it is
significantly shorter.

Comment: Thank you @Valdi_Bo . I tried. But I get a error with real data. "TypeError: ('slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method', 'occurred at index id_1')"

It worked with sample data, but couldn't work real data.
Sample data and real data have same types.

Comment: If my program works OK with your test data (included in the question) then the program is OK. So the source of the problem is your data. Check e.g. whether all elements of *startday* and *endday* are of *integer* type. You can also try to cast them to *int*, changing to: *rr = row.values[int(sd):int(ed)]* (I assume that the error was in this line).